# Inquiry about random shuffle

Tags: c++, random, hardware, shuffle

I asked a question about this yesterday, but the topic was put on hold because of miscommunication. So I was trying to run a program to shuffle elements in a vector. This portion is completed with the following code:

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
random_shuffle(scores.begin(), scores.end());
```

I accept that the code runs without error and that other machines see a random shuffle, but when I run this code the values clearly do not shuffle. This is part of a larger program and when others run the program, the values are clearly shuffled, but when I try running the program over and over again, the values do not shuffle. I'm wondering, possibly naively, if this is because I'm running it on a MacBook, or possibly I don't have my files and folders organized properly. Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>::const_iterator iter;

    cout << "Creating a list of scores.";
    vector<int> scores;
    scores.push_back(1500);
    scores.push_back(3500);
    scores.push_back(7500);

    cout << "\nHigh Scores:\n";
    for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nRandomizing scores.";
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    random_shuffle(scores.begin(), scores.end());
    cout << "\nHigh Scores:\n";

    for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nSorting scores.";
    sort(scores.begin(), scores.end());
    cout << "\nHigh Scores:\n";
    for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I imagine this will run properly for everyone though, which is why I am so confused.

Comment: Where are you importing `time` from? If it's coming from `datetime` for example, you'll get the same seed every time.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure because I'm pretty new to programming, but I know that when I print the value of time, it is different every time I run the program. But ctime I think.

Comment: How is this question different from the closed one you asked yesterday?

Comment: The question is different because yesterday I was assuming there was something that was wrong with the code, but that is clearly not the case. Now I'm ask if anyone knows if this could be a result of my hardware or some organizational thing I've done.

Comment: You should only call `srand()` once at the start of your program, not every time you call `std::random_shuffle()`. Otherwise a tight loop will keep seeding the same value because `time(0)` only changes once per second. Also you should print out what `static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))` gives you to see that's happening there.

Comment: Oh and it is best to qualify your functions to make sure you are getting the correct ones and not some spurious symbol: `std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));`.

Comment: @Galik How would I go about printing that? Like I said, I'm pretty new to c++.

Comment: Honestly, *don't use* `random_shuffle` *in the first place*. Prepare a proper urng  and use [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) (#3 in the list). `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated as of C++14. That said, it should be *trivial* to write a [**mcve**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem. Do so, and update your question.

Comment: @SalvatoreConte You can do `std::cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)) << '\n';`

Comment: @Galik Thanks. I ran that piece of code, and the seed changes every time I run the program, so the random_shuffle isn't being seeded with the same thing every time.

Comment: @WhozCraig I notice that when I run the example program on the reference page you sent me, it has the same issue. The values only shuffle the first time I run the program, but when I run the program again, the values do not shuffle again. Do you know if that is intentional?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Of course, you're shuffling *three* things. I don't suppose [this makes a difference](http://ideone.com/bOBkQy).

Comment: @WhozCraig So I tried running your code in Eclipse and it was really not happy, but when I ran it in xcode, the values were shuffled differently every time I ran the code, although running my previous code in xcode didn't solve the problem for that code.

Comment: So the issue is definitely that srand is not seeding random_shuffle. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If your program is doing something untoward (e.g. undefined behaviour) that can affect how it accesses anything, including data related to system time.

There is potentially a concern with quality of implementation of your standard library, so it returns a constant value rather than a different value each time it is called.    Some implementations only access the system clock once, so multiple calls of `time()` will return the same data each call.   `time()` is not required to have a granularity better (less than) a second, so a fair few implementations pick an approach for efficiency rather than accuracy.

Calling `time()` multiple times in quick succession - including running your programs multiple times - can mean the same time is measured.

Without a small but complete sample of code that exhibits your problem, and a description of the environment you run it in, it is not possible to give definitive advice.

It's more likely that your problem is in your code or in how you use your program, rather than a specific problem with your standard library or hardware.    But all the associated probabilities of a problem are non-zero.

Comment: It must be how I'm using the program, because others have run the exact code and had it run properly with the vector shuffling randomly, so I don't think it is a coding related issue. I'm not really sure what you mean by how I use my program though.

Comment: How you use the program includes describing what you mean by "running it over and over again".  For example, do you use a batch file that runs it a few times within a second?   How many elements are in the vector?  Are they fixed programatically, or read from a file?     [I note you have noiw edited your post to include code which only places 3 elements in the vector - which means there are only a total of six possible combinations, which means it doesn't take much to get repetition].

Comment: So I ran the code again with more elements and they are clearly being shuffled now, so thank you for that. But, when I run the program again and again, the elements are shuffled in the exact same order as the first time, and the same thing happens on the random_shuffle/shuffle reference page. TBH, I'm not savvy enough to know how to run a batch file as I'm still new to this.

Comment: Also, I've checked and the value of the seed is changing every time I run the program, despite the same output.